# Control volume of Pulse Audio from command

Tags: 12.04, sound, pulseaudio

I load the modle-loopback for Logitech mic and bluetooth device using the sinks. After doing that now I am hear the audio from both but the audio coming from devices is very high.  So is there any way to control the audio of this devices from command prompt?

Comment: Try `alsamixer`

Comment: I got the answer to control the volume of sinks from command. But now I want to know the sink volume status means how much percent it is?

Answer (score 1):

I got answer

I used `pactl set-sink-volume 0 20%`  and it is working great for pulseaudio volume control

```
pactl set-sink-volume <sink index> <voulme %>
```